# Home Fragment does not implement DialogListener interface

Tags: android

In MainActivity I implemented switching between three fragments:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        replaceFragment(HomeFragment())

        binding.bottomNavigation.setOnItemSelectedListener {
            when(it.itemId) {
                R.id.nav_home -> replaceFragment(HomeFragment())
                R.id.nav_stats -> replaceFragment(StatisticFragment())
                R.id.nav_profile -> replaceFragment(ProfileFragment())
                else -> {}
            }
            true
        }

    }

    private fun replaceFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
        val fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
        val fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()

        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout, fragment)
        fragmentTransaction.commit()
    }

}
```

I also have a **DialogListener**, which is needed to transfer data between the VariableDialogFragment and HomeFragment classes:

```
interface DialogListener {
    fun onConfirmAddDialogResult(data: String)
}
```

**VariableDialogFragment**:

```
class VariableDialogFragment(private val layoutResourceId: Int) : DialogFragment() {

    private lateinit var dialogListener: DialogListener

    // checking the implementation of the DialogListener interface
    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        try {
            dialogListener = parentFragment as DialogListener
        } catch (e: ClassCastException) {
            throw ClassCastException("Parent fragment must implement DialogListener")
        }
    }


    @SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId")
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        getDialog()!!.window?.setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.round_corner_20)
        val view = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, container, false)

        val saveButton = view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.saveAddButton)
        val cancelButton = view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.cancelAddButton)
        saveButton.setOnClickListener {
            handleSaveButtonClicked()
            dismiss()
        }
        cancelButton.setOnClickListener {
            dismiss()
        }

        return view
    }


    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        val width = (resources.displayMetrics.widthPixels * 0.90).toInt()
        val height = (resources.displayMetrics.heightPixels * 0.40).toInt()
        dialog!!.window?.setLayout(width, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
    }
```

**HomeFragment**:

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment(), DialogListener, FinalWaterListener {
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentHomeBinding
    private var dataList: MutableList<HistoryItem> = mutableListOf()
    private lateinit var database: AppDatabase

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        database = AppDatabase.getInstance(requireContext())
        setAddButton()
    }

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance() = HomeFragment()
    }

    private fun setAddButton() {
        binding.customPopupAdd.setOnClickListener {
            VariableDialogFragment(R.layout.add_fragment).show(childFragmentManager, "add fragment")
        }
    }

    override fun onConfirmAddDialogResult(data: String) {
        addHistoryItem(data)
        currentDrinkCount = (binding.currentCountWater.text.toString().toInt() + data.toInt()).toString()
        binding.currentCountWater.text = currentDrinkCount
        binding.percentCountWater.text = "${calcPercent()}%"
    }
```

I used to implement all this in MainActivity and everything worked, but then I switched to fragments and immediately started giving an error. I tried to fix the onAttach method, but nothing works and gives the following **error**:

E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.wattercount, PID: 25371
java.lang.ClassCastException: Parent fragment must implement DialogListener
at com.example.wattercount.dialogs.VariableDialogFragment.onAttach(VariableDialogFragment.kt:35)
at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performAttach(Fragment.java:3068)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.attach(FragmentStateManager.java:490)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:265)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1943)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1845)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1782)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run(FragmentManager.java:565)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8757)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parent of VariableDialogFragment must implement the `DialogListener` interface you created.

I think in your case the parent would be the activity `MainActivity`  so you would need to add the interface like this:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), DialogListener {
    override fun onConfirmAddDialogResult(data: String) {
        //TODO do something with the callback
    }
}
```

I would also recommend not throwing an error on the `onAttach()` function, is better to check if the parent class implements the necessary interface. Something like this:

```
override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    super.onAttach(context)
    if (context is DialogListener) {
        dialogListener = context
    }
}
```